# Getting mouse movement delta while Locking the cursor with win32

Tags: c++, winapi, game-engine, game-development

So I have this issue where I want get my mouse movement so that I can rotate my camera using my mouse. The issue is that I also want the cursor to be locked in place. So any attempts to capture my mouse movement failed because I couldn't really move my mouse.

I tried the `ClipCursor` and the `SetCursorPos` function but both failed in the same way that my mouse movement delta was always zero. For getting this mouse movement I tried to simply get the position before and after the message pump and then get the difference but when locking the cursor that approach doesn't work anymore.I also tried using Raw Input Data like so:

```
        RAWINPUTDEVICE rawInputDevices[1];
        rawInputDevices[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;  // Mouse
        rawInputDevices[0].usUsage = 0x02;      // Mouse
        rawInputDevices[0].dwFlags = 0;
        rawInputDevices[0].hwndTarget = Window::GetWindowHandle(); 

        RegisterRawInputDevices(rawInputDevices, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));
```

```
        case WM_INPUT:
            UINT dataSize;
            GetRawInputData(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam), RID_INPUT, nullptr, &dataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

            if (dataSize > 0)
            {
                std::vector<BYTE> buffer(dataSize);
                if (GetRawInputData(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam), RID_INPUT, buffer.data(), &dataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == dataSize)
                {
                    RAWINPUT* rawInput = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(buffer.data());

                    if (rawInput->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
                    {
                        Events::mouseDelta.x = rawInput->data.mouse.lLastX;
                        Events::mouseDelta.y = rawInput->data.mouse.lLastY;
                    }
                }
            }
```

that worked to some extend but for some reason I got like an insane amount of input lag using this and I am also getting weird problems when I try to rotate my camera(using the mouse movement delta of course) and moving in some direction, which I do not get when using the approach I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Try [Performing a Buffered Read of Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input#performing-a-buffered-read-of-raw-input) to resolve lag and smoothness.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT There are some things there which for me are undefined. Do I need to import some other headers besides "Windows.h"?

Comment: Only [QWORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) is necessary. But according to my test, the Buffered Read of Raw Input needs `Sleep` to accumulate the data. Maybe you should decrease the process time of `WM_INPUT`.